# Asp.net core compilation issue with VS2017 community edition

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have installed VS 2017 Community edition with below workload on my machine (Windows-7 64 bit).

1. ASP.Net and Web Development.
2. Azure Development
3. .Net Desktop Development.
4. .NET Core cross-platform development.

I'm getting error message as 'Unable to attach to application 'dotnet.exe' (PID:2472) using 'xxxx-user' The address is not valid for this context'
while compiling the simple Asp.net core application.

Tried some workarounds like repairing the VS installation, deleting bin and obj folder still facing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried launching VS in Admin mode?

Comment: yes, i'm running VS in admin mode always.

Comment: Do you get the message whlie **compiling** or while **debugging** (running with F5 or the play button)? Sounds more like debugging though. Are you using IIS Express?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Could you check the Windows Event Viewer and see if there is any additional information liked in there?

Comment: @RichardEverett Event Viewer logs this one -> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/XXX' with physical root 'C:\Users\XXX\source\repos\XXX\XXX\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5339.tmp"', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 0.

Comment: @Tseng Issue while debugging and with IIS Express